# I want to dynamically change class with respect to status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

I am using react and using map function . I want to use conditionally change class when my payment status will change  I use if else statement but its give that status is not define .

```
<table className="table display expandable-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.no</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      {/* <th>Transaction no.</th> */}
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Mode of payment</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {paymentstate.map((value, key) => {
      let statusClassName;

      if (value.status === "pending") {
        statusClassName = "badge badge-warning";
      } else if (value.status === "success") {
        statusClassName = "badge badge-success";
      } else if (value.status === "cancel") {
        statusClassName = "badge badge-danger";
      }

      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          <td>{key + 1}</td>
          <td>{value.name}</td>
          {/* <td>9879278397823</td> */}
          <td className="font-weight-bold">₹{value.amount}</td>
          <td>{value.payment_mode}</td>
          <td>21 Sep 2018</td>
          <td className="font-weight-medium">
            <div className={statusClassName}>Completed {value.status}</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

During the initial render, the items list may be an empty array or some items in the list may not have the status property defined.

Alternative, you can create an object like this in your component

```
const STATUS_BADGET_COLOR = {
pending: 'badge badge-warning',
success: 'badge badge-success',
cancel: 'badge badge-danger'
}
```

and use it in your template `className={STATUS_BADGET_COLOR[value.status]}`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bnu9m4?file=src%2FApp.js)